# How to use Data Spaces within Data Cloud like a sandbox environment?

Tags: datacloud, salesforce-cdp

I'm in a process of importing data from external system (Sitecore) into Data Cloud. By default I only have one Data Space available connected to a Prod Salesforce Org. There are concerns about not having dedicated sandbox like environment for testing as Sitecore data is preferred to come from/to their sandbox before pushing it to Prod for personalisation.

1. Does anyone know what are the best practices recommended by Salesforce for utilizing Data Spaces or equivalent features within Data Cloud to simulate a sandbox-like environment for safe testing and validation purposes?
2. How can Salesforce Data Cloud, in its current configuration without a dedicated sandbox environment, effectively manage and segregate test data from external systems like Sitecore for personalization testing?
3. How to ensure that this test data does not interfere with the real customer data already imported in Data Cloud for example MC/Sales Cloud Production data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Vladimir Silak advised ''the data spaces provide logical data segregation within a singular org. If you need to separate test data sources from production you can either consider using filters on data streams when you associate those with data space. Or alternatively you can configure completely separate data streams for your various environments and only associate those with respected data spaces.
Once your data ingestion is configured the implementation of all other aspects of the solution will be independent per data space. Therefore you can have different segments, activation targets etc to perform your validation and integrations into the dev/test environments.
Key thing to keep in mind that unlike sandbox there is no code/configuration promotion functionality across data spaces. Therefore if you configure dev/test environment, prod setup will still require some/most of manual rework.''